# Unity Debug with Rider-EAP On Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, unity-game-engine, rider

Jetbrains publised Project Rider – A C# IDE

- [Windows](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/riderRS-144.4571.exe)
- [OS X](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/riderRS-144.4571.dmg)
- [Linux](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/riderRS-144.4571.tar.gz)

For Unity Debug with Rider-EAP On OSX I find [instruction](http://www.leroyshirto.co.uk/2016/03/unity-debug-with-rider-eap-on-osx/).

How i can Unity Debug with Rider on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -ano | ?{($_ -like "*"+$(Get-Process -Name Unity).Id) -and ($_ -like "* LISTENING *") }
```

This command return line like

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:56760          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6760
```

So, I need use port **56760**.

Other like [this instruction](http://www.leroyshirto.co.uk/2016/03/unity-debug-with-rider-eap-on-osx/).